# Reorder csv rows and columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, sorting

I have [This](https://expirebox.com/download/a3bddd7600a631daa2b93a422224abe0.html) csv file I want the output to be in a html table where the 
Example :

fish;4;1;33 fish should be at 1 row column 4.

dog;5;2;66 dog should be at 2nd row column 5

I have come here:

```
    var data ='Major;1;2;29/nMinor;2;3;29/nRowNum;1;1;23/njk;2;2;23/n44;1;‌4;23';
 function insertData(id, data) 
    {
     var table = document.getElementById(id);
     var dataRows = data.split("/n");
     if (table) { 
    dataRows.forEach(function(s) { 
    var x = s.split(';');
     table.rows[x[2]].cells[x[1]].textContent = x[0];
     }); }
```

This code inserts major and minor where it should but how can do the same by uploading a document?Basically `var data = //uploaded doc` 
I have tried to do it with

```
myReader.onload = function(e) {
 var content = myReader.result;
```

but no good result,I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: For all practical purposes, I recommend that you use some CSV Parsing library like [this one](https://github.com/knrz/CSV.js/)! After all CSV parsing is [**not** just `data.split()`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: to tell the truth I just dnw jquery.csv.js so I will have a look at that,since my deadline is within 2h

Answer (score 0):

```html
    
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body onload="myFunction()">
        
        <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">
        
        <p id="demo"></p>
        
        <script>
        function myFunction(){
                 var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        
        
        input.addEventListener("change", function () {
          if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var myFile = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
              // You can process your file here
              var datasplitted = data.split("/n");
              // you do all you want
            });
            
            reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
          }   
        });
    
               }
        </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: data is not defined,even making the changes take a look at all https://expirebox.com/download/3596c16aae9f15ec279484ec6effe34c.html

Comment: Did you try to run the snippet? I am sorry! I don't have my computer now.

Comment: idk if you have read what am I trying to do,but I dont want just to read a csv...I have already done this,please read the question

Comment: From your question, I understood that you wanted to do the splitting from a document you imported. Because in your question, the `data` is a constant string. If not, could you clarify what you want ? Why do mean by no "good result" ?